# Is it possible in any way (using C++ preprocessor etc) to replace shared_ptr<T> with T$, weak_ptr<T> with T%, and unique_ptr<T> with T?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, shared-ptr, syntactic-sugar

So far it seems like the answer is no.

Which is unfortunate given how much more visually noisy code becomes with `shared_ptrs` all over the place.

Comment: If you have shared pointers all over the place, you probably need to re-evaluate the way you C++.

Comment: I'm working on a compiler now, I pass tokens back and forth between everything, so my screen is littered with shared_ptrs etc. This is my first compiler project, so maybe I'm doing it wrong. :\

Comment: Tell more about your compiler project.... BTW, I believe C++ is not the best language for a compiler....

Comment: It's nothing special, I want to get a working compiler for a {}; language without using lex etc. just to understand how it works. So as my lexer reads code it creates tokens which get passed to the parser, which then makes them children of higher expressions and so on. There is a lot of creation going on, and the easiest way to keep track of it is with shared_ptr.

Comment: ...But now that T* has been replaced with shared_ptr<T>, the code has become significantly more annoying to read. When I used raw pointers the horizontal size of the code was at least roughly proportional to its complexity. Now it's completely random. shared_ptr kills code readability.

Comment: C++ should really adopt something like T$, T% and T! for shared<T>, weak<T> and unique<T> pointers. $ has long been dying for a proper job in C++ anyway. Pretty code matters.

Comment: The thing is, most people don't have this problem of shared pointers all over the place. So this wouldn't do anything to make their code pretty, just yours. And there is nothing unique about a making a compiler that makes it prone to having more shared pointers.

Comment: I haven't found clear best practices for using shared_ptr, so I'm just going with my gut, but I'm new both to compilers and to shared_ptr, so maybe I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: Yes, probably. While I can't make any specific recommendations without seeing your code, I can give a general guideline. Don't be afraid of passing things and returning things by value. C++ is a value semantics language, and C++ compilers are are optimized for this.

Answer (score 4):

With C++11, one possible way to do that now is to use *aliases* (which are cleaner imo than macros). E.g. for shared pointers, you could do:

```
template<typename T>
using Shared = std::shared_ptr<T>;
```

Then, use it like the following:

```
Shared<int> myInt; // Is in fact a std::shared_ptr<int>
```

EDIT: [**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03906f28242ad694).

Comment: I'll add it as a comment but, do note that it solves your immediate problem of code readability, but doesn't address the fact that you may have to rethink the way you're designing your program if you have too many shared pointers in the first place.